# Dangling CNAME Record Issue

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dkim, amazon-ses

I have been trying to setup the DKIM CNAME Signing for one of my sub domains with Amazon SES and for some reason the CNAME is behaving oddly:

Eg.

The following:

```
dig @4.2.2.4 pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com
```

at times returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @4.2.2.4 pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10537
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. 170 IN CNAME support.formsdotstar.com.
support.formsdotstar.com. 170   IN  A   23.239.84.67

;; Query time: 223 msec
;; SERVER: 4.2.2.4#53(4.2.2.4)
;; WHEN: Wed May 11 22:56:02 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116
```

and at other times returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @4.2.2.4 pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31484
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. 174 IN CNAME pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial.dkim.amazonses.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dkim.amazonses.com. 774 IN  SOA ns-386.awsdns-48.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 232 msec
;; SERVER: 4.2.2.4#53(4.2.2.4)
;; WHEN: Wed May 11 22:56:01 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 226
```

Initially I thought it was a propagation issue, but it appears with the same DNS server.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Given that this issue revolves around your domain name, don't censor it. Give us the domain so we can have a look... and when you *do* censor domains, don't use valid ones - use the `example.com/org/net` ones set aside for that purpose.

Comment: Also. "propagation" (more accurately, caching) is still entirely possible on the same nameserver. `4.2.2.4` likely responds to *many* individual nameservers behind the scenes. Note the differing remaining TTLs.

Comment: I have put back the actual domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your four nameservers for formsdotstar.com are returning different answers:

```
$ dig @ns1bqx.name.com pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. 300 IN CNAME pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial.dkim.amazonses.com.

dig @ns2dfg.name.com pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. 300 IN CNAME support.formsdotstar.com.
support.formsdotstar.com. 300   IN  A   23.239.84.67

$ dig @ns3dkz.name.com pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. 300 IN CNAME pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial.dkim.amazonses.com.

$ dig @ns4ghm.name.com pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
pznfjjljalcr5ocdaxrjia27nbf7cial._domainkey.support.formsdotstar.com. 300 IN CNAME support.formsdotstar.com.
support.formsdotstar.com. 300   IN  A   23.239.84.67
```